# maven both include and exclude patterns to run tests from command line

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

With `-Dtest=<include-pattern>` I can include tests that match include-pattern, and with `-Dtest=!exclude-pattern` I can exclude tests that match exclude-pattern.
How can I use both include and exclude patterns in command line option?

Next is not working for me: `-Dtest=<include-pattern>,!<exclude-pattern>`

If I use `-Dincludes=**/<include-pattern> -Dexcludes=**/<exclude-pattern>` exclude-pattern seem to be applied only.

Is there any way I can configure both include/exclude patterns from command line?

Comment: Maybe you can use `-Dincludes` and `-Dexcludes`? The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) for the `test` parameter explicitely says, that it overrides those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use quoting while passing comma separated values (e.g. `-Dtest="<include-pattern>,!<exclude-pattern>"`).
This works for me and this is how it's planned to work.